org.slf4j.Logger SystemErr in console and create file .log
I am developing the following class for Java Version 8:
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Utilidades {
    
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Utilidades.class);
    
    public static String fecha(Boolean horaInicial, boolean esAyer) {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        if(esAyer) {
            localDateTime = localDateTime.minusDays(1);
        }
        
        String pattern = "";
        if(horaInicial) {
            pattern = "00:00:00";
        } else {
            pattern = "HH:mm:ss";
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'" + pattern);
        
        String date = localDateTime.format(formatter);
        log.info("slf4j");
        return date;
    }


}

The problem is that the log.info("slf4j"); line prints the following:
[3/10/24 8:46:19:155 CEST] 000000c4 SystemErr     R [WebContainer : 0] INFO es.seguridadsocial.palexws.utilidades.Utilidades - slf4j

I use the following configuration in the logback.properties file:

Configuración del logger de SLF4J
Nivel de registro
logging.level.root=INFO

Appender
logging.appender.STDOUT.class=ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
logging.appender.STDOUT.encoder.class=ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
logging.appender.STDOUT.encoder.pattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n


and the one in the logback.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
 
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>myApp.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
 
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
 
  <logger name="com.prueba.proyecto" additivity="true" level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>
</configuration>

I would like to know how to remove SystemErr from the console and generate a log file. I use WAS9 as a server.
Quit SystemErr an create log file
